# Updating Firebase deletes already existing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm building an app with Firebase, and I recently used this code to update a list/dictionary of "posts" inside a user dictionary. Take a look:

```
Firebase *baseRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://<MY-APP>.firebaseio.com"];

NSString *userPostsPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@/posts", userId];

NSDictionary *postRef = @{ postId : postDescription };

[baseRef updateChildValues:@{
                             userPostsPath : postRef
                             // here I'd have a similar update
                             }withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref) {
                                 handler(error, ref);
                             }];
```

This works on the first update, but the second time I do this, all the existing posts are removed. However, changing the code to this:

```
Firebase *baseRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://tonightdb.firebaseio.com"];

NSString *usersPostsPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@/posts/%@/", userId, postId];

[baseRef updateChildValues:@{
                             usersPostsPath : postDescription,
                             // similar update path
                             }withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref) {
                                 handler(error, ref);
                             }];
```

Updates Firebase correctly.

**What is the difference between the two?** How come the first didn't work?

**Edit**

Is it possible to do:

```
Firebase *baseRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://<MY-APP>.firebaseio.com"];
NSString *newKey = [baseRef childByAutoId];
```

Then use that key do do an update that looks like this:

```
[baseRef updateChildValues:@{
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/posts/%@/", newKey] : // something
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/posts/%@/members/<something>", newKey] : // something
withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref) {
            handler(error, ref, task);
        }];
```

Basically to issue multiple updates to the same path in the same request, that doesn't exist beforehand while avoiding overwrite issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example translate into an instruction to update:

```
"users/posts" = { "postid1": postDescription }
```

The second example translates to:

```
"users/posts/postid1" = postDescription
```

Being a computer program, the Firebase server takes a quite literal interpretation of the instructions you give it. It takes each update instruction and replaces the data at the path (the part before the `=`) with the value (the part after the `=`).

Knowing that, you can see that in the second example it will write the `postDescription` at `users/posts/postid1`. This will replace the existing description for that post, but that is probably what you had in mind.

The second example writes `{ "postid1": postDescription }` at `users/posts`. This replaces the existing value at that location, so you're essentially replacing all existing posts with the new/updated one. That is probably not what you had in mind.

**Update**

If you're creating a new object and fanning out the key to multiple locations, you can make use of the fact that `childByAutoId` is a pure client-side operation:

```
let newRef = ref.childByAutoId()
let newKey = newRef.key
ref.childByAppendingPath("child1").childByAppendingPath(newKey).setValue("one")
ref.childByAppendingPath("child2").childByAppendingPath(newKey).setValue("two")
```

Comment: What's the best approach if I wanted to create two new posts or "paths" in the same call, while still using `childByAutoId`? Trying to write these updates as efficient as possible to draw minimal mobile data and resources

Comment: `childByAutoId` is a client-side operation, so you can get the key from it. . I'll write a quick snippet and add it to my answer.

Comment: I see, does the algorithm to obtain `childByAutoId` remain the same regardless of location? Meaning could I do `let newRef = ref.childByAutoId()` whereas `ref` is the root of Firebase, and use that key for a different location? That way, if for some reason needed, you could "simulate" a new Firebase ref and use that to obtain a new unique key?

Comment: The push ids that Firebase creates are described here: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html